# SQL Insert by subquery inside update query

Tags: sql-server, query, subquery

I want to Write a single query that updates columns in one table and insert rows in another table.

something like this

```
       update
            applications
       set
            applications.rejected = 1,
            (
                INSERT INTO rejection_reason (column1, column2)
                                VALUES (value1, value2)
            )
       where 
        applications.id  = 123
```

I know I can do it with 2 queries but I want to do it in single one. is there any way to update and insert in 2 tables with single query?

Comment: Can you clarity what `values` you're expecting to be inserted elsewhere? Where are they coming from? You might be able to use [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to do this, but you'll need to add some details here.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one query?

Comment: Short answer: No.  Database operations are *atomic* and thus can only do one action at a time.  However, you can wrap the separate statements in a transaction so the data isn't committed unless both statements succeed.

Comment: @bbaird are you [sure about that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=399a65d7f5eea33a3a3204434d835f4c)?

Comment: @ErikDarling TIL about Update with OUTPUT.

Comment: @ErikDarling Do you have the time to pop that in an answer?

Comment: @JohnK.N. I don't know if it's a good answer without more details from our wayward OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using trigger. Based on limited information on the schema of both tables, you may have to create Insert trigger on rejection_reason table which will update the table applications.
Assuming the rejection table has a application_id column which can be used as a link between the two tables.

e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER i_rejection_reason ON rejection_reason 
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN  
    UPDATE
        applications
    SET
            applications.rejected = 1,
   WHERE applications.id  = inserted.application_id  

END
```

Below insert will update the applications table via trigger.

```
INSERT INTO rejection_reason (column1, column2, application_id)
VALUES (value1, value2, 123)
```

PS : Consider impact of multirow inserts (refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure) and test for performance as well before using it in production environment.